# Java script image changer with one button

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello guys i am new to web development and i wanted to see how DOM (addEventListener) works.
So i wanted to make slideshow with one image that containts 2 images.
This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="picture2.png" alt="">
    <button type="picture" name="button">Click Me</button>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my css

```
button{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 7%;
}
img {
  display: none;
}
```

And this is my js

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener("click",showPic,false);

function showPic(e) {
  img.style.display="block";

}
```

All i want to do is when i click on the button the first time picture of girl to show and when i click second time the picture of the baby to show. Please help me :)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhvYb.png

Comment: I think You want to change the image on click of button. Am I correct

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you haven't set up the second image and then, when you do, there needs to be code that somehow toggles between them.

There are many variations on how to do this, but IMHO the simplest and most scaleable is to keep the URLs for the images in an array and then upon the click of the button, update the `img` `src` to the next array item. When you reach the end of the array, start over at the beginning.

As a side (but important) note, you are using `.getElementsByTagName()` with an index, which is not a very good technique for getting a DOM element reference [and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Instead, you should use modern APIs such as `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` (discussed in the previous link).

Finally, a form field element like a `button` should only have a `name` attribute when it is nested inside of a `form` that will be submitting data somewhere and the `value` of that element is desired to be submitted along with the rest of the `form` data.

```js
// Store URLs in an array
let urls = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Check_mark.svg/28px-Check_mark.svg.png", "https://www.barcoproducts.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1de18e47886e8a56e4b449f2e3cefe99/R/W/RW925_630.jpg"];

let index = 0; // Keep a reference to which URL is being used

// There are different ways to get element references:
var img = document.querySelector("img");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click",showPic);

function showPic(e) {
  // Don't work with inline styles. Just work with
  // CSS classes and the element's classList
  img.classList.remove("hidden");
  
  // Adjust the image source
  if(index < urls.length - 1){
    index++;  // Increase the index
  } else {
    index = 0; // Reset index
  }
  
  // Change the image source
  img.src = urls[index];
}
```

```css
button{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 7%;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

img { width:50px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Check_mark.svg/28px-Check_mark.svg.png" alt="image" class="hidden">    
    <button type="picture" id="button">Click Me</button>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```